# Android email intent only *sometimes* does not send attachment?

Tags: android, android-intent

In an app I have, users submit files to a specified email address a lot. It seems 95%+ have no problem, but this is a particular issue that seems to affect some users, and only sometimes. But frequently enough to be annoying.

**Their email sends, but there is no attachment.** They will try 2,3,4 times and **eventually** it will send with the attachment. From one user, I have learned they use Gmail and *DO* see the attachment prior to pressing "send".

**The users' Android API levels vary from 19 to 29 and everything in between.**

Here is the code for composing the email intent:

```
public int emailSubmission(File fileToSend)
{
    Uri uri = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", fileToSend);
    else
        uri = Uri.fromFile(fileToSend);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intent.setType("text/message");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@email.com"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello world!");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    try
    {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email submission..."));
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        logNonFatalException(e);
        return 2;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

It seems pretty standard, but I can't figure out what is causing this problem? I also do not know if it is specific to Gmail. Is there anything else I can even try to get rid of this intermittent issue? All "email intent" Android code I see online looks just like this, specifically for attachments and EXTRA_STREAM and the URI code.

Comment: What kind of attachment is it? The MIME type?

Comment: @Elletlar it is a ZIP file, but I don't believe I set any type of mime type for the attachment anywhere, I haven't seen that in any docs/examples before

Comment: Don't know. Could it be the size? GMail has a 25MB limit. Worth attaching one over the limit to see what happens? What about simulating different types of failed uploads in GMail then sending? Could take a look the message/rfc822 structure of the emails with the missing attachments in Thunderbird for example, View -> Message Source. Not sure with GMail, but most clients will generate something like multipart/mixed: text/plain and  application/zip. Only other thing, Android file system is tricky. Could be it only happens when the file is in a certain location, external storage for example.